# Javascript throwing a error after adding and running google places autocomplete code

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I added the code below to my MVC application and although google places autocomplete in my text field works, some JavaScript file throws an error now when one of the javascript files gets used or rendered.
here is the error in visual studio. It errors occurs when I hit the submit button on my main page.

> Unhandled exception at line 626, column 256 in eval code
>
> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

here is the code I added to the head tag in _Layout.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=places"></script>
```

then I added the code below at the end of the body section in _Layout.cshtml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var input = document.getElementById('location');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
</script>
```

and finally here is the form with the text field in index.cshtml that uses the places autocomplete.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Results", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        <input type="text" name="location" id="location" placeholder="Search For A Studio" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value='Submit' type="submit"/>
    </p>
}
```

the error gets thrown when the line below gets hit in the debugger.

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

I read other posts with the same error message and I tried

```
var input = document.getElementById('<%=location.ClientID%>');
```

but it still errors.

Updated! - I tried adding a hard coded value to input like below and now I get this error message both when the page first loads and also when I press submit.

> 0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getAttribute'

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        
        var input = "brighton";
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        //debugger;
    </script>
```

Comment: I also tried. var input = document.getElementById('location').value; but the error messagesays the value is undefined or null. It looks like getelementid isn't working properly but not sure why?

Comment: I moved the text box from the view results.cshtml to my _Layout.cshtml page and it worked with no errors. Why? Does the javescript need to be in the same file as the element it is using? Both my javascript and the text box are now in the same file (_Layout.cshtml) before they were in two different files. This doesn't make sense because renderbody() in _Layout.cshtml calls the results.cshtml view before the javascript code is called. So it should be active in the page right?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

indicates that the error is happening when loading the scripts on the view being rendered inside of the _Layout Master Page.

Search for this on your View :

```
@section Scripts {}
```

By default Visual Studio adds jqueryval to template generated CRUD views, so if you're working with the templates, your page might have this on the end

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Try removing the jqueryval loading on your view. If jquery validation is needed, load it in the _Layout

Comment: I looked at my view that is being called after I press the submit button, it doesn't contain any @section Scripts area. So I tried adding it to the end of my _Layout page just below the closing html tag and tried it but no go. It still doesn't work.

Comment: one that I noticed is that when I debug the javascript I see that the value in var input = document.getElementById('location'); is null. It seems like I should have a value there, maybe not?

Comment: I think the problem is in the order the scripts are being loaded.